# file_get_contents: how to get json (does not work my badcode)?

Tags: php, json

there is a landing page, it has the following structure:

```
index.php
 |
 +-assets
 |    +-html - here all parts of the landing page - php and html files (header, footer, form ...) 
 |    |  |
 |    |  +-data - here are json files for loading data 
 |    |  |  |
 |    |  |  +-persons.json - employees 
 |    |  |  |
 |    |  |  +-news.json - news
```

The index.php file simply contains the call to the required modules from 'assets/html/' . That is so

```
<?php 
    require_once '/assets/html/file.php';
?>
```

The 'data' directory (full path 'assets/html/data') contains json files in which all the information that needs to be displayed.

In any file (for example top_news.php) in the html directory ('assets/html') I write:

```
<?php
    $url = 'data/news.json'; //path to json file 
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

The problem is file_get_contents ($url) doesn't see the file it needs.

I get a response (on screen)

'Warning: file_get_contents(data/news.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\tnv4\html\top_news.php on line 3'

I tried to locate (use) the data directory (with attached json files) in the assets folder (that is, so assets/data/news.json).

But calling the news.json file with

```
$url = '../data/news.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
```

doesn't work either.

Locally I use openserver, php_7.1

On server: centos 7.9, PHP 5.4.16

Please tell me how to get the json file correctly?

Comment: `'/assets/html/file.php';` is not the same as `'./assets/html/file.php';`, the leading `/` is the most rootest part of the drive, i.e `C:` or `/`, not `C:\OpenServer\domains\tnv4\html\`

Comment: Thank you,
i write in root (in index.php file i write like this: 'assets/html/file.php').
That is, I write relative code: relative to the index.php file, which is located in the site.com directory, in the 'www' directory.
That is, the resulting file is located like this: 'www/site.com/index.php'.
And the 'assets' directory and so on are located like this: 'www/site.com/assets'

Comment: So did you fix it? from what you wrote it's not clear... it seems like you are confusing file location with url on the browser... when you are doing a file_get_contents you either give a full url or for example : './assets/html/file.php'; which is the right way to reach a file which sits in assetsts/html/ dir above the current dir you are.